# How can I map a hardware key to another key on my Apple Mac Book Pro (Catalina)

Tags: macos, keyboard, macos-catalina

Just got a new Mac Book Pro (Catalina OS), but was disgusted to find there is no hardware Esc key. As a developer this is a must. I did find you could map 4 special keys to Esc (things like Shift-lock) but I don't want to do this. I want to map § to Esc. I'm sure this is possible with some OS hackery, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I put it into my ~/.bash_profile, I only need it for vim.

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000064,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000029}]}'
```

On other mac keyboards it might not be 64, so you can test by mapping keys to 'A'
0x700000004 is A

All codes https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

If you screw it up: hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[]}'